# Problemas con la cabecera Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

No se porque la cabecera se daña de esta forma.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var dataTable = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
 language: {
      lengthMenu: "Display _MENU_ records per page",
      zeroRecords: "Nothing found - sorry",
      info: "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
      infoEmpty: "No records available",
      search: "",
      searchPlaceholder: "Buscar",
      loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
      processing: "Procesando....",
      paginate: {
        first: "primero",
        last: "ultimo",
        next: "siguiente",
        previous: "anterior"
      },
      infoFiltered: "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    },
    processing: true,
    scrollX: true,
    order: [],
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],

});
```

```css
.table-responsive{
  border: 0px;
}
.table{
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tblDistribucionZonas">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Puesto en el top</th>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Zona</th>
              <th>Venta</th>
              <th>Ingreso</th>
              <th>Iva</th>
              <th>Descuento</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>01</td>
              <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
              <td>775,731,615.04</td>
              <td>652,014,223.20</td>
              <td>123,717,391.84</td>
              <td>40,579,517.40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>06</td>
              <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>           
              <td>503,927,312.80</td>
              <td>423,468,330.43</td>
              <td>80,458,982.37</td>
              <td>25,358,819.59</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>05</td>
              <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
              <td>239,755,868.94</td>
              <td>201,475,520.14</td>
              <td>38,280,348.80</td>
              <td>8,067,695.74</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>04</td>
              <td>TOLIMA</td>
              <td>58,224,961.73</td>
              <td>48,928,539.28</td>
              <td>9,296,422.45</td>
              <td>2,681,183.20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td> 
              <td>10,817,773.14</td>
              <td>9,090,565.60</td>
              <td>1,727,207.54</td>
              <td>439,624.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
              <td>3,879,908.19</td>
              <td>3,260,427.04</td>
              <td>619,481.15</td>
              <td>116,095.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>03</td>
              <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
              <td>2,712,981.42</td>
              <td>2,279,816.31</td>
              <td>433,165.11</td>
              <td>291,163.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>8</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>1,128,287.50</td>
              <td>948,140.75</td>
              <td>180,146.75</td>
              <td>99,302.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>08</td>
              <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
              <td>758,934.95</td>
              <td>637,760.46</td>
              <td>121,174.49</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>07</td>
              <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
              <td>0.30</td>
              <td>0.30</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
          <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: es un problema tipico de datatable...

Comment: sabes como arreglarlo

Comment: tienes mas tablas en la misma pagina o solo esa ?

Comment: solo esa tabla tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero actualizar y usar la ultima version de datatables he realizado tu table sin problemas:

```js
var dataTable = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
 language: {
      lengthMenu: "Display _MENU_ records per page",
      zeroRecords: "Nothing found - sorry",
      info: "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
      infoEmpty: "No records available",
      search: "",
      searchPlaceholder: "Buscar",
      loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
      processing: "Procesando....",
      paginate: {
        first: "primero",
        last: "ultimo",
        next: "siguiente",
        previous: "anterior"
      },
      infoFiltered: "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    },
    processing: true,
    scrollX: true,
    order: [],
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],

});
```

```css
.table-responsive{
  border: 0px;
}
.table{
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tblDistribucionZonas">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Puesto en el top</th>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Zona</th>
              <th>Venta</th>
              <th>Ingreso</th>
              <th>Iva</th>
              <th>Descuento</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>01</td>
              <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
              <td>775,731,615.04</td>
              <td>652,014,223.20</td>
              <td>123,717,391.84</td>
              <td>40,579,517.40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>06</td>
              <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>           
              <td>503,927,312.80</td>
              <td>423,468,330.43</td>
              <td>80,458,982.37</td>
              <td>25,358,819.59</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>05</td>
              <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
              <td>239,755,868.94</td>
              <td>201,475,520.14</td>
              <td>38,280,348.80</td>
              <td>8,067,695.74</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>04</td>
              <td>TOLIMA</td>
              <td>58,224,961.73</td>
              <td>48,928,539.28</td>
              <td>9,296,422.45</td>
              <td>2,681,183.20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td> 
              <td>10,817,773.14</td>
              <td>9,090,565.60</td>
              <td>1,727,207.54</td>
              <td>439,624.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
              <td>3,879,908.19</td>
              <td>3,260,427.04</td>
              <td>619,481.15</td>
              <td>116,095.95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>03</td>
              <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
              <td>2,712,981.42</td>
              <td>2,279,816.31</td>
              <td>433,165.11</td>
              <td>291,163.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>8</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>1,128,287.50</td>
              <td>948,140.75</td>
              <td>180,146.75</td>
              <td>99,302.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>08</td>
              <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
              <td>758,934.95</td>
              <td>637,760.46</td>
              <td>121,174.49</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>07</td>
              <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
              <td>0.30</td>
              <td>0.30</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
              <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
          <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahora bien algo que corregi en tu codigo javascript fue que tenias demas un cierre de llaves tenias asi al final:

```
..
..
 }
});
```

cuando solo deberia estas:

```
});
```

y en ocasiones se necesita reinicializar el datatable con :

```
"bDestroy": true
```

para mayor detalle te sugiero leer esto:

[Documentacion datatable options](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Pero como puedo utilizar el "bDestroy": true porque lo intento y no funciona